# Get the culture info from a time zone or time zone offset c#

Tags: c#, date, timezone, globalization, cultureinfo

I'm trying to format dates based off of culture info.  The problem is I don't know the culture info, all I know is the time zone and time zone offset. So I would like to be able to get the culture info depending on which time zone, in order to format a date string.  For example if the time zone is eastern standard US time then the date format would be MM/DD/YYYY but if the time zone is Australian then I would need to format the date DD/MM/YYYY.  I know the culture to time zone is a one to many relationship but if I'm going in the reverse order and I have the specific time zone then it should be a one to one relationship.  Anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: It makes little sense, a timezone like Western European Time covers many cultures.  Stop thinking that a timezone is helpful at all, you need to know the culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, they are unrelated.  You might *think* their is some correlation, and you may be able to find examples where they are, but then you'll find many where they are not.

Consider that my culture may be `en-US`, even if I'm visiting or living in Japan.  The culture code means "English as spoken in the United States".   It doesn't refer to the current physical location of a user.

Also, if you only have a time zone offset, you certainly can't make any correlation, as there are countries in both North American and South America that share the same offset at some point or another, but use different date formats.

If you have an actual *time zone* identifier, then it depends on which type you have.  For location-based IANA identifiers such as `"America/New_York"`, you can look up the country code, and guess the format from there - though you'll still have the foreign visitor issue I described above.  Also, there are IANA identifiers like `"Etc/GMT-2"` that are not country specific.  And then if you have Windows time zone identifiers (such as those used with `TimeZoneInfo` in .NET), there are several that span multiple countries.  There's no guarantee every country that uses the time zone uses the same date format.

Take a look at [date formats by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) on Wikipedia.  You'll see that there are many places where more than one date format is in use, depending on context.  [The case of the Philippines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_Philippines), is of particular interest, as they use use both MDY and DMY formats.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.  Seems like a better idea to go off of what country rather than go off of a time zone.

Comment: You said you didn't have the country or culture though, right?  Or is this a web app?  You may be able to get it from the browser if so.

Comment: Now i'm just getting the user language from the request made by the client.  If that doesn't exists then something else will be used in it's place.

Comment: The [W3C's article on this](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales) is worth reading.  They basically recommend *starting* with the `Accept-Language` header, but offering your user control over changing it somewhere within your site.

Comment: Another thing I've noticed is that for some reason when a UTC time is converted using TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc, the format is correct (after converting to string and specifically for australian server with date in DD/MM/YYYY).  What's even more strange is that when running a server on my local machine the date is not in the correct format.  Even after changing the machine region, language and time zone to australia...

Comment: While in `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` types, *there is no format or culture*.  Whatever you're observing occurs later, when the values are used to produce strings.

Comment: Ya that's why i didn't get how it was being formatted but that value is returned from a function and then append to a string like: returnedDateTimeValue + ": " + someOtherString...I guess I'm missing something else that's going on in the code though...thanks for all your help

Comment: When you do that, it implicitly calls `ToString` with no argument, which uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, and the default *general* format for that culture.  instead, be explicit and you can control the culture and format.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes a lot more sense now.  I was hoping I would see something like that in the documentation somewhere but couldn't find it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only with timezone and zone offset is a little bit impossible define  date format. For example, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), Canada,USA and Mexico have some common timezone and time offset but date format is different